# Migrate jira project from one jira to other using jira-rest-java

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I have such problem: I need to migrate Jira project from one Jira instance to other. I have implemented

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new    AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    URI uri = new URI(JIRA_URL);
    JiraRestClient client = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(uri, JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);
    Promise<User> promise = client.getUserClient().getUser("user");
    User user = promise.claim();
    Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql("project =TESTPROJECT");

    for (Issue issue : searchJqlPromise.claim().getIssues()) {
        System.out.println(issue.getDescription());
    }
```

Here I think I can get all issues from project I need.
So how can I create Jira project and issues using Java code and get issues from this code and set then to new project?

Comment: Its not requirement to do it exactly from code, the main goal to transfer project from one jira to another in some automatic way, because it has thousands of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So if it is not necessary to do it from code, and as it is from Jira to Jira, it would be quite easy:

- You have to create a backup of the proyect data you want to import
- then you have to import it using the JIRA tools.

You can find the export/import options if you navigate to Admin>system>Import project.

There you will find this link to the "Oficial howto" : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira060/restoring-a-project-from-backup-370705784.html

I guess this is going to be easier than code

Regards,

Comment: Can I do backup only specified project from jira not all projects?

Comment: I guess you can do it all at one, but im not sure. There is another option "Restore system", and "Backup system", but im not sure how do they work. Anyway, probably you could do it for more than one project

Comment: let us know if you achieve it !

Comment: the problem is that i need to do it from jira server to jira cloud instance

Comment: hum... i have never worked with cloud version... is it not valid the proccess described in that link?